# Installing a CPAN module using a remote compiler

Tags: perl, redhat-enterprise-linux, cpan

I need to install the XML::Parser module. Unfortunately, that package uses expat. Due to security concerns, I am not allowed to install the dev package of expat. making the CPAN Module fail to install.I have access to another machine without that limitation. I was told I need to compile on the second machine and move the binaries over.

Any Ideas on how to properly do that.

RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compile elsewhere, and install the result. [CentOS](http://centos.org) of the same version as RHEL should work fine for this.

Comment: can that be done via the CPAN shell, or the CPANPLUS shell?